# Swift fill array backwards with reserveCapacity

Tags: arrays, algorithm, swift, allocation

I have a generic algorithm in which an array whose size is known in advance must be filled in *reverse* (from the highest index to the lowest).  If the array weren't being filled in reverse, the most efficient way to do this would be calling `reserveCapacity` and then `append`-ing the values.  In other words,

```
var arr = [T]()
arr.reserveCapacity(minimumCapacity: knownCapacity)
// append values using algorithm
```

However, that will add the first value produced by the algorithm at index `0`.  I need it to start at index `knownCapacity - 1` and work backwards.

How could this be accomplished in Swift?  Of course I can add values starting from `0` and then reverse the array, but reversal is an expensive operation.  Ideally, there would be some sort of `reserveBackwardsCapacity` and `prepend` system of methods, or a data structure built specifically for this built into the language, but I haven't been able to find either.

I would use `[T](count: knownCapacity, repeatedValue: )` and just fill from the back, but because the algorithm is generic (it should work for any type `T`) I don't have any way of knowing what to put for `repeatedValue` (and filling the array with values just to be overridden would be expensive and unnecessary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea: don't initialize your array until the first value is about to be added. When you have the first value, initialize your array using your `knownCapacity` and the first value as the `repeatedValue`. Then add additional items as they become available from the back of the array to the front.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know enough about the implementation of Swift arrays to understand how the performance would compare to building the array using `append` and then reversing the whole thing, but you could try:

```
arr.insert(item, atIndex: 0)
```

... to prepend items.

Comment: That would work, but I suspect that Swift would have to copy all of the elements forward by one every time.

Comment: Probably, yes. An alternative: require that T conform to a protocol that defines a `Zero()` function that returns something like 0, and fill your array with whatever value is returned.

Comment: Or: don't initialize your array until the first element is about to be added, then use that element to fill your array, then work backwards from the end of the array as additional values arrive.

Comment: That works, and it makes sense but feels a little bit kludgy.  Still, I think that's the best solution available right now.  If this weren't a comment I'd mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: I agree with your feeling about it. Maybe someone else will have a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, another possible solution is to create a protocol defining a parameterless initializer, and make the `T` type implement it - this way you can create an instance of `T`:

```
protocol Initializable {
    init()
}

func initArray<T: Initializable>(knownCapacity: Int) -> [T] {
    var arr = [T](count: knownCapacity, repeatedValue: T())
    return arr
}
```

If you're using your own types, just make them implement the `Initializable` protocol:

```
class MyClass : Initializable {
    required init() {
        // do something
    }
}

var array: [MyClass] = initArray(5)
```

If using existing types instead, make them implement the protocol using an extension - for instance:

```
extension Int : Initializable{
}

let array: [Int] = initArray(10)
```